# Converting DateTime string to 24 hours format DateTime data type in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert a simple DateTime string like "12/12/12 14:00:00" to 24 Hours DateTime Type object however upon conversion it gives me 12 hours format as below:
"12/12/12 02:00:00". How can I get my desired 24 hours format datetime object in c#.

Basically What I am trying to do is that I have two different string variables for date and time. I am combining them and converting them into datetime. Which after concatenation are fine but converts to 12 hours after conversion into datetime.

```
string app_time = Convert.ToDateTime(appointment.ScheduledTime_Short).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                string app_date = Convert.ToDateTime(appointment.ScheduledDate_Short).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                string fdt = app_date + " " + app_time;
                appointment.ScheduledDate = startDateTime;
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried multiple ways by defining format as well as culture information. Right now I am doing as:  string cdt = Convert.ToDateTime(fdt).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(cdt);

Comment: @BilalAmjad  that looks like it should work.  You should edit your question and put that in there, and then explain why it isn't working for you.

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: hmm, a little confused.  the date time object is technically not in any format.  It can represent a date and time based on the system. You can display it in 24 hour time like you do on the first line with ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Comment: Lemme check guys.

Comment: By the way if it is the case then how can I prevent c# to pick format of my PC?

Comment: What you're doing makes no sense. DateTimes are stored internally in no particular format. The formatting only happens for _display_ purposes. Don't run the .format() method until the time you want to show the date to a human being, and don't expect that when you convert that formatted _string_ back into a DateTime object (as per your 2nd line of code) that it stays in that format - it doesn't, it goes back to being a DateTime object, not a string. So if you then look at that in your debugger it'll just show you it in whatever is its default format

Comment: Try to understand the difference between the way the date is _stored_ and the way its _displayed to users_. The second line of code in your example is not needed at all. The first line should be only executed at the time when you want to show the date on screen.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: The edit has not improved this question. For a problem as simple as this you should **easily** be able to provide a [Mcve].

Answer (score 4):

```
12 Hour Date Format:  DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
24 Hour Date Format : DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt")
```

Answer (score -1):

Your **dt** variable is DateTime. This means it contains the DateTime value that you assigned. ***What it shows is just your local settings***. You should configure your editor settings accordingly